# How to delete all parents with no children in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Let's consider the SQLAlchemy [example for a basic relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html):

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    children: Mapped[List["Child"]] = relationship(back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("parent_table.id"))
    parent: Mapped["Parent"] = relationship(back_populates="children")
```

How can I delete all `Parent`s without `Child`ren?

I tried this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

with Session(engine) as sesssion:
    session.query(Parent).filter(
        func.count(Parent.children) == 0
    ).execution_options(is_delete_using=True).delete()
```

But this causes:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) misuse of aggregate function count()
> [SQL: SELECT parent_table.id
> FROM parent_table, child_table
> WHERE count(parent_table.id = child_table.parent_id) = ?]
> [parameters: (0,)]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using sqlite3 as the backend, the SQLAlchemy [`count`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.count) function will map to the corresponding [aggregate function `count`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count), and at the top of the documentation page describes the correct syntax.  The way your query was constructed do not reflect this, hence the error.

There are actually a couple ways to do this.  Since you want parents with no children to be pruned, just simply selecting all the parent_ids and filter by `NOT IN` on the parent's `DELETE` clause will achieve this.  MCVE for the setup follows:

```py
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, delete
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine, func

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    children: Mapped[List["Child"]] = relationship(back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    parent_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("parent_table.id"))
    parent: Mapped["Parent"] = relationship(back_populates="children")

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.add(Parent())
session.add(Parent(children=[Child()]))
session.add(Parent(children=[Child()]))
session.add(Parent(children=[Child()]))
session.add(Parent(children=[Child(), Child()]))
session.add(Parent(children=[Child(), Child()]))
```

We created a parent with no children, 3 parents with 1 child, 2 with 2 children.  Using the `NOT IN` query:

```py
print("%d parents total" % session.query(Parent).count())
query = (
    delete(Parent)
        .where(Parent.id.not_in(select(Child.parent_id))
    )
)
session.execute(query)
session.commit()
print("%d parents total" % session.query(Parent).count())
```

The above query corresponds to this:

```sql
DELETE FROM parent_table WHERE (parent_table.id NOT IN (SELECT child_table.parent_id 
FROM child_table)) RETURNING id
```

Should generate the following output:

```
6 parents total
5 parents total
```

If you wish to use `COUNT` to do the filtering, e.g. you want to delete parents with exactly 1 child, you will need to form the subquery first

```py
subq = (select(Child.parent_id, func.count(Child.id).label('child_count'))
    .group_by(Child.parent_id)
    .subquery()
)
```

Then use that as a query.  Here we delete all parents with 1 child (which should affect 3 parents):

```py
query = (delete(Parent)
    .filter(Parent.id.in_(
        select(subq.c.parent_id)
            .filter(subq.c.child_count == 1)
    ))
)
session.execute(query)
session.commit()
print("%d parents total" % session.query(Parent).count())
```

The above queries together should generate the following:

```sql
DELETE FROM parent_table WHERE parent_table.id IN (SELECT anon_1.parent_id 
FROM (SELECT child_table.parent_id AS parent_id, count(child_table.id) AS child_count 
FROM child_table GROUP BY child_table.parent_id) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1.child_count = ?) RETURNING id
```

As expected, should produce the following output:

```
2 parents total
```

Naturally this latter method will result in orphaned children using the included schema as set up by the model in the question. As other questions have answered how this might be addressed, I won't get into that here.

Answer (score 1):

OkaY lets try with subquery:

```
from sqlalchemy import exists
subquery = session.query(Parent.id).filter(~exists().where(Child.parent_id == Parent.id)).subquery()
session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.id.in_(subquery)).delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

Or:

```
session.query(Parent).filter(
~Parent.children.any()).delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

Or:

```
session.query(Parent).filter(
~Parent.children.any()).delete(synchronize_session=False)
```

Or:

```
session.query(Parent).filter(~Parent.children.any()).delete()
```

Using the any() function to check if children exist